# How to prevent a django model from being related to itself on a m2m

Tags: django, django-models

Lets say I have the following models:

```py
class Person(models.Model):
    related_people = models.ManyToManyField('Person',
                                            blank=True,
                                            related_name='ret_related_people',
                                            through='RelationshipType')

class RelationshipType(models.Model):
    person1 = models.ForeignKey('Person', related_name='rel_back_1')
    person2 = models.ForeignKey('Person', related_name='rel_back_2')

    type = models.CharField(max_length=16)
```

Is there any way to prevent a `Person` from being related to itself?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Untested:

```
class Person(models.Model):
    related_people = models.ManyToManyField('self',
                                        blank=True,
                                        related_name='ret_related_people',
                                        through='RelationshipType',
                                        symmetrical=False)

class RelationshipType(models.Model):
    from_person = models.ForeignKey('Person', related_name='from_people')
    to_person = models.ForeignKey('Person', related_name='to_people')
    type = models.CharField(max_length=16)

    def clean(self):
        if self.from_person == self.to_person:
            from django.core.exceptions import ValidationError
            raise ValidationError("People can't have a relationship to self")
```

Comment: It works in the admin, but I need to call th clean method manually on code.

Comment: Interesting, when you call the `add` method from the related field it is not calling `clean()`? Perhaps it is worth overriding this methods on the RelatedManager...